# Ideal hashing method for wide distribution of values?

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, hash

As part of my rhythm game that I'm working, I'm allowing users to create and upload custom songs and notecharts. I'm thinking of hashing the song and notecharts to uniquely identify them. Of course, I'd like as few collisions as possible, however, cryptographic strength isn't of much importance here as a wide uniform range. In addition, since I'd be performing the hashes rarely, computational efficiency isn't too big of an issue.

Is this as easy as selecting a tried-and-true hashing algorithm with the largest digest size? Or are there some intricacies that I should be aware of? I'm looking at either SHA-256 or 512, currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All cryptographic-strength algorithm should exhibit no collision at all. Of course, collisions necessarily exist (there are more possible inputs than possible outputs) but it should be impossible, using existing computing technology, to actually find one.

When the hash function has an output of *n* bits, it is possible to find a collision with work about *2<sup>n/2</sup>*, so in practice a hash function with less than about 140 bits of output cannot be cryptographically strong. Moreover, some hash functions have weaknesses that allow attackers to find collisions faster than that; such functions are said to be "broken". A prime example is MD5.

If you are not in a security setting, and fear only *random* collisions (i.e. nobody will actively try to provoke a collision, they may happen only out of pure bad luck), then a broken cryptographic hash function will be fine. The usual recommendation is then [MD4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1320). Cryptographically speaking, it is as broken as it can be, but for non-cryptographic purposes it is devilishly fast, and provides 128 bits of output, which avoid random collisions.

However, chances are that you will not have any performance issue with SHA-256 or SHA-512. On a most basic PC, they already process data faster than what a hard disk can provide: if you hash a file, the file reading will be the bottleneck, not the hashing. My advice would be to use SHA-256, possibly truncating its output to 128 bits (if used in a non-security situation), and consider switching to another function only if some performance-related trouble is duly noticed and measured.

Comment: Yes, this answered my question perfectly. Indeed, I'm only concerned about random collisions, so I'll look into SHA-256 and MD4. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using it to uniquely identify tracks, you *do* want a cryptographic hash: otherwise, users could deliberately create tracks that hash the same as existing tracks, and use that to overwrite them. Barring a compelling reason otherwise, SHA-1 should be perfectly satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

If cryptographic security is not of concern then you can look at this [link](http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/doobs.html) & [this](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/index.html). The fastest and simplest (to implement) would be Pearson hashing if you are planing to compute hash for the title/name and later do lookup. or you can have look at the superfast hash [here](http://sites.google.com/site/murmurhash/superfasthashtestresults). It is also very good for non cryptographic use.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with something like an `md5sum`? Or, if you want a faster algorithm, I'd just create a hash from the file length (mod 64K to fit in two bytes) and 32-bit checksum. That'll give you a 6-byte hash which should be *reasonably* well distributed. It's not overly complex to implement.

Of course, as with all hashing solutions, you should monitor the collisions and change the algorithm if the cardinality gets too low. This would be true regardless of the algorithm chosen (since your users may start uploading degenerate data).

You may end up finding you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist (in other words, possible YAGNI).

Answer (score 0):

Isn't cryptographic hashing an overkill in this case, though I understand that modern computers do this calculation pretty fast? I assume that your users will have an unique userid. When they upload, you just need to increment a number. So, you will represent them internally as userid1_song_1, userid1_song_2 etc. You can store this info in a database with that as the unique key along with user specified name.

You also didn't mention the size of these songs. If it is midi, then file size will be small. If file sizes are big (say 3MB) then sha calculations will not be instantaneous. On my core2-duo laptop, sha256sum of a 3.8 MB file takes 0.25 sec; for sha1sum it is 0.2 seconds.

If you intend to use a cryptographic hash, then sha1 should be more than adequate and you don't need sha256. No collisions --- though they exist --- have been found yet. Git, Mercurial and other distributed version control systems use sh1. Git is a content based system and uses sha1 to find out if content has been modified.